# UIViewController when UITableViewCell is Pressed

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am trying to make an app so that when the cell in the `UITableView` is pressed, it opens a new `ViewController` with the same image and label used before in the initial cell that was clicked.

Here are my cells:
[image: My Cells]
Here is the array I am using:

```
let alligator:NSArray = ["American Alligator","American Crocodile","Mugger Crocodile","Saltwater Crocodile"]
```

Here is the `numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAt`:

```
 public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return(alligator.count)
}


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell4 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell4", for: indexPath) as! AlligatorViewCell
    cell4.alligatorImage.image = UIImage.init(named: alligator[indexPath.row] as! String + ".jpg")
    cell4.alligatorLabel.text = alligator[indexPath.row] as? String
    return(cell4)
}
```

Here are my outlets for the detail View Controller:

`@IBOutlet var detailImage: UIImageView!
 @IBOutlet var detailLabel: UILabel!`

And here is the `didSelectRowAt`

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    detailImage.image = UIImage.init(named: alligator[indexPath.row] as! String + ".jpg")!
    detailLabel.text = alligator[indexPath.row] as? String
```

**The problem is that when I press the cell, I get the error, `fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while Unwrapping Optional`**

Comment: What's the problem? Have you even tried segueing to another viewcontroller? There are many posts on SO on how to do this; I encourage you to take a look at those.

Comment: The segue portion works fine, it's just that there is a problem with the label and image

Comment: Then you are probably calling a picture that doesn't exist. Make sure the string in UIImage.init matches you uploaded file name.

Comment: However, the same picture works fine when I just use it in the cell itself.

Comment: And the error is coming from the first line of the `tableViewDidSelectRowAt` method yes?

Comment: Correct, its coming from that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your error is occurring because `detailImage` does not exist when you call it.

From what I understand, these outlets are in your base view controller, but they are referring to objects in your detail view controller, which isn't allowed. Thus when you try and call them, they won't pass anything giving a value of nil.

Thus it is not about the UIImage being initialized.

You need to make the IBOutlets within the detailViewController class, and then pass the values from your cell to these outlets through your `prepareForSegue` func.

Let me know if you have questions about this.

**Edit**

Let's say your detail view controller has the detailImage property, then you could do something like this (in your base ViewController)

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let controller = segue.destination as! UIViewController //your detail controller
    controller.detailImage = myImage //where myImage is a property of your base view controller
}
```

**Edit**

You could set the myImage property in the view controller when your cell is tapped just as your tried before. Then myImage could be set to the detailImage in the prepareForSegue func. So something like this:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    myImage = UIImage.init(named: alligator[indexPath.row] as! String + ".jpg")!
    ...
```

**Edit**

You should be using `myImage` like this:

```
var myImage: UIImage?
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        myImage = UIImage.init(named: alligator[indexPath.row] as! String + ".jpg")!
        ...
```

Comment: Can you explain how to pass the value through a prepare for segue function

Comment: I don't understand what should go in the place of myImage, as the property alligatorImage used in the cellForRowAt is specific to another class called AlligatorViewCell.

Comment: The `myImage` variable needs to be set outside of the func so it can be accessed by both funcs.

Comment: However, when I try to add the myImage outside of the func, there is an error that says `use of unresolved identifier indexPath`

Comment: @Pannu Check my updated answer. You should probably study some of the foundations of Swift as you don't seem to understand how variable initialization works.

Comment: Is there anything that should be added to the DetailViewController, since the error `fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while Unwrapping Optional` has popped up.

Comment: You need to connect the detailImage outlet to your image in your detailViewController storyboard

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: @Pannu No problem :D